# React Cors issue with ExpressJS

Tags: reactjs, express, cors

**EDIT:** I am getting the following error when trying to access my server:

> POST http://localhost:3001/user/login 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong for this error to keep occurring:

React:

```
export default class Account extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isLoggedIn: false,
    };
    this.login = this.login.bind(this);
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const cookies = new Cookies();
    const user = cookies.get('user');
    const pass = cookies.get('pass');
      this.setState({processing: true})
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/user/login', {
        credentials : 'omit',
        method      : 'POST',
        body : JSON.stringify({
          username : user,
          password : pass
        })
      })
      .then(res  => res.json())
      .then(json => {

        // If the login was successful
        if (json.success) {
          this.setState ({
            isLoggedIn: true
          })
        }

        // Otherwise
        else {
          this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Invalid username or password',
            processing  : false
          });
        }

      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          errorMessage: 'An unknown error occurred',
          processing  : false
        });
      });
  }
render() {
  if(this.state.isLoggedIn) {
    return (<p> Logged In</p>);
  }
  else {
    return (<p> Not Logged In</p>);
  }
}}
```

Express:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {

  return User
    .findOne({username: req.body.username})
    .then (user => user.authenticate(req.body.password))
    .then (auth => {
      if (auth.user !== false) {
        req.session.user = auth.user.user
      }
      res.json({success: auth.user !== false})
    })
    .catch(() => res
      .status(500)
      .json({success: false})
    );
});
```

This error isn't giving much info on what I could be doing wrong but it could be to do with cors.

Comment: @AtinSingh I seen this but if I use the cors package, I get the following error: `POST http://localhost:3001/user/login net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: .`catch((err) => res //add err here and console.log
      .status(500)
      .json({success: false})
    );` Can you please do this and tell us the results? If err is too big you can just tell us relevant part. (maybe in err.response.data)

Comment: My console reads: `Cannot read property 'authenticate' of null`

Answer (score 0):

There problem is not in your code ( probably ); since a request will be considered as `SAME-ORIGIN` if `domain`, `port` and `protocol` all be the same in source and destination of the request; but your request is heading to port `3001` not  `3000` which violates the same-origin rule; hence `CROSS-ORIGIN`; two other part are ok, both on `localhost` and `http` but port different; you need to configure your server to respond properly to `OPTION`(pre flight) request to fix this properly;

Comment: I am now using the cors pakage and have edited it to show what my error is now but not sure how to fix it

Comment: @Shauna check out [this article on enable-cors](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html)

Answer (score 0):

Have you added a `proxy` parameter to the `package.json`? I use this setup frequently but have not seen the issue you are seeing. Try adding the following parameter to the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mern",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/"
...
}
```

And then all of your API calls can just be `/api` because the proxy parameter has been set.

Comment: I have edited it now to show what I'm doing as I'm now using the cors package. Should I still add this to package.json when using the cors package?

Comment: @Shauna no his solution is different than that, it's supported in create-react-app out of the box; this will solve your development problem

Answer (score 0):

Your console reads: `Cannot read property 'authenticate' of null`.

In your .catch of api -

```
.catch(() => res
  .status(500) // you are sending 500 (internal server error) irrespective of what your actual error is//
  .json({success: false})
);
```

Your error is -

```
  return User
    .findOne({username: req.body.username})
    .then (user => user.authenticate(req.body.password)) //can read authenticate of null because user is null i.e This user does not exist in your DB. //
```

I suggest add err in your catch block as parameter and do proper error handling. This issue is the case of improper error handling.

Comment: The username I'm inputting does exist in the DB though

Comment: @Shauna You need to make sure you are searching the right key and all because according to error your findOne did not return any user. Check if this is correct `{username: req.body.username}`

Comment: It seems like this isn't right but any example I see for this shows it is right.

Comment: @Shauna Are you using mongoose?

Comment: I am using Mongoose yeah I have the connection of this in my app.js file